# How to get a resized ImageElement from an .svg image?

Tags: canvas, svg, dart

I need to draw an image into a canvas which is obtained from an .svg .
I am currently using the following code:

```dart
active_toolbutton = query("#${event.target.id}").clone(false);
active_toolbutton.width = 100;
active_toolbutton.height = 100;
context.drawImageScaled(active_toolbutton, placeX, placeY,
  active_toolbutton.width, active_toolbutton.height);
```

This work with Chrome but not in Firefox, is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in dart:html. Please fill in all of the detail you can at www.dartbug.com/new

Comment: Done, https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10076 .

Comment: I've never heard of `context.drawImageScaled` . `context.drawImage` does exactly what you want and takes the same parameters? Maybe that's something through dart?

Comment: It seems that drawImage() is a standard HTML5 canvas method http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp .

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have found the answer. There is no standard behavior that defines that  .svg images should be re-scaled using their scalar capabilities. In fact there are some cases (e.g. CSS background) in which different browsers handle the scaling differently.

I have found a solution which is to use a 3rd party javascript library that will render SVGs into a canvas. I have used [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) , with dart javascript interopt librar.

The code:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
...
    active_toolbutton = new CanvasElement();
    active_toolbutton.width = 100;
    active_toolbutton.height = 100;
    var options = js.map({ 'ignoreMouse:': true,
      'ignoreAnimation': true,
      'ignoreDimensions': true,
      'scaleWidth': 100,
      'scaleHeight': 100});
    js.context.canvg(active_toolbutton, event.target.src, options);
```